# Wrapper class for adding elements to HashSet

Tags: java, hash-map, wrapper, hashcode

I have many object of class `Test`. I want to be sure that among them, there are no two objects `o1` and `o2` where `o1==o2`. In order to achieve that, I want to add them all to a `HashSet` and check if `hashSet.size() == numberOfInitialObjects` .

In order to ensure that the potential future changes in `equals` method of the  `Test` class will not affect my implementation, I wrote a simple wrapper so that instead of adding `Test` objects to the `HashSet`, the wrapper objects will be used. The code as such:

```
private class HashSetWrapper {

        private final Test component;

        public HashSetWrapper(Test component) {
            this.component = component;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.component);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final HashSetWrapper other = (HashSetWrapper) obj;
            return this.component == other.component;
        }
    }
```

Is my approach OK, or are there more suitable ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: I think you are worrying prematurely. Why will you think future changes in `Test.equals()` might break equivalence? If so, you have other things to worry about then.

Comment: @h.j.k. This part of app required to check if five Test values (test1, ..., test5) sent to a method (it means, potentially references to the same objects as well) "points" to different objects (objects can be equal in sense of equals method, but not ==).

Comment: Ah ok... got what you mean after reading your reply and [@rolfl](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/109098/24141)'s answer.

Comment: All you have to do is override `equals()` method in your class. Every class extends `Object` class, and `Object` class has `equals()` method. When you override `equals()` method in your class, you can compare two objects of the same class.

Comment: @ASWINS I've converted your post into a comment, since it's not really reviewing the OP's code, which is what we expect of answers on this site. That said unless I'm mistaken, when overriding `equals` you should always also override `hashCode`, especially so when the intent is clearly to add a class to a `HashSet`, where each item's `hashCode` would be involved in the keying. At least, that's how it works in .net and I'd assume Java works similarly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - correct - overriding just the equals will cause issues in the HashSet where 2 values that are equal(), but have different hashCodes can exist. See the hashCode contract: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 10):

Why build your own implementation when you can use the features available in the Java standard libraries?

[IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) gives you all the features you need, and a Java Stream/collector will allow you to extract the map easily from your collection....

```
Collection<Test> tests = .....
Map<Test,Test> uniques = tests.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
     t -> t,
     t -> t,
     (t,u) -> t,
     IdentityHashMap::new))
```

Now, if the size of the `uniques` is the same as the `tests`, you're good. The `uniques` Map is an IdentityHashMap where the key values are all identical instances (using `==`). It supports a null key/value so that should be fine too.

Answer (score 2):

A general improvement on "add everything then count" is to fail as soon as a duplicate is found.

```java
  public static <T> boolean uniqueInstances(Collection<T> items) {
    Set<T> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<>()); // Stand-in for (non-existent) IdentitySet
    return items.stream().allMatch(set::add); // add() returns false if element already existed
  }
```